# Matrix Inverse algorithm doesnt work inside my Code

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-multiplication, inverse, matrix-inverse

My group and I are trying to create a bridge simulation. For that we need to calculate the inverse of a big matrix. So we got an open source algorithm which after testing it with this site: `http://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/inversematrix.htm` seems to work properly. But when we use it in our program it returns weird matrices. The problem seems to be obvious. It must be the matrix not being given to the function right. So I put some code in the function that prints the matrix which arrived there. And that was absolutely right so we don't know what the problem is. Then  I tested the function again with a very big matrix and not in our program and again it worked properly so I have the feeling that there is some weird interaction between our program and the function.

The Code of the function:

```
public static double[][] inverse_matrix(double[][]in){

    int st_vrs=in.length, st_stolp=in[0].length;
    double[][]out=new double[st_vrs][st_stolp];
    double[][]old=new double[st_vrs][st_stolp*2];
    double[][]neu=new double[st_vrs][st_stolp*2];


    for (int v=0;v<st_vrs;v++){//ones vector
        for (int s=0;s<st_stolp*2;s++){
            if (s-v==st_vrs) 
                old[v][s]=1;
            if(s<st_stolp)
                old[v][s]=in[v][s];
        }
    }
    //zeros below the diagonal
    for (int v=0;v<st_vrs;v++){
        for (int v1=0;v1<st_vrs;v1++){
            for (int s=0;s<st_stolp*2;s++){
                if (v==v1)
                    neu[v][s]=old[v][s]/old[v][v];
                else
                    neu[v1][s]=old[v1][s];
            }
        }
        old=prepisi(neu);       
        for (int v1=v+1;v1<st_vrs;v1++){
            for (int s=0;s<st_stolp*2;s++){
                neu[v1][s]=old[v1][s]-old[v][s]*old[v1][v];
            }
        }
        old=prepisi(neu);
    }
    //zeros above the diagonal
    for (int s=st_stolp-1;s>0;s--){
        for (int v=s-1;v>=0;v--){
            for (int s1=0;s1<st_stolp*2;s1++){
                neu[v][s1]=old[v][s1]-old[s][s1]*old[v][s];
            }
        }
        old=prepisi(neu);
    }
    for (int v=0;v<st_vrs;v++){//rigt part of matrix is invers
        for (int s=st_stolp;s<st_stolp*2;s++){
            out[v][s-st_stolp]=neu[v][s];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

static double[][] prepisi(double[][]in){
    double[][]out=new double[in.length][in[0].length];
    for(int v=0;v<in.length;v++){
        for (int s=0;s<in[0].length;s++){
            out[v][s]=in[v][s];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

The Code where we use it:

```
  public class SimulationFenster extends JFrame{


int fe_anzahl;
double brueckenlaenge;
double hoehe;
double breite;
double flaeche;
double material;
double[][] kraftvektor;
double[][] steifigkeitsmatrix;
double[][] gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix;
double[][] ergebnisvektor;

double fe_laengepixel;
double fe_laengereal;

JButton einstellungen;
JButton zurueck;
Zeichnen zeich;

double[] xKoordinaten;
double[] yKoordinaten;
Schnittpunkt[] punkte;

double scale;
Icon hintergrund=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hintergrund.png"));

public SimulationFenster(int fe_anzahl,double brueckenlaenge,double breite,double hoehe,double material,double[][] kvektor){
    fe_anzahl++;
    this.fe_anzahl=fe_anzahl;
    this.brueckenlaenge=brueckenlaenge;
    this.hoehe=hoehe;
    this.breite=breite;
    this.material=material;
    this.kraftvektor=kvektor;
    this.flaeche=hoehe*breite;

    xKoordinaten=new double[this.fe_anzahl];
    yKoordinaten=new double[this.fe_anzahl];

    punkte=new Schnittpunkt[fe_anzahl];
    for(int i=0;i<fe_anzahl;i++){
        punkte[i]=new Schnittpunkt();
    }
    fe_laengepixel=410.0/(fe_anzahl-1);

    fe_laengereal=brueckenlaenge/(fe_anzahl-1);
    scale=1.0;

    double E=material;
    double A=breite*hoehe;
    double I=breite*Math.pow(hoehe, 3)/12;
    double L=fe_laengereal;
    steifigkeitsmatrix=new double[][]{
            { E*A/L,                     0,                   0,-E*A/L,                    0,                   0},
            {      0, 12*E*I/Math.pow(L,3),-6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2),     0,-12*E*I/Math.pow(L,3),-6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2)},
            {      0, -6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2),             4*E*I/L,     0,  6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2),             2*E*I/L},
            {-E*A/L,                     0,                   0, E*A/L,                    0,                   0},
            {      0,-12*E*I/Math.pow(L,3), 6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2),     0, 12*E*I/Math.pow(L,3), 6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2)},
            {      0, -6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2),             2*E*I/L,     0,  6*E*I/Math.pow(L,2),             4*E*I/L}};
    gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix=new double[3*fe_anzahl][3*fe_anzahl];
    for(int i=0;i<fe_anzahl-1;i++){
        for(int j=3*i;j<3*i+6;j++){
            for(int k=3*i;k<3*i+6;k++){
                gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix[j][k]=gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix[j][k]+steifigkeitsmatrix[j%6][k%6];
            }
        }
    }

    gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix=streichen(gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix,0);//FEHLER vermutet
    gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix=streichen(gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix,0);//FEHLER vermutet
    gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix=streichen(gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix,gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix.length-2);//FEHLER vermutet
    gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix=streichen(gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix,gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix.length-2);//FEHLER vermutet
    kraftvektor=streichen(kraftvektor,0);//FEHLER vermutet
    kraftvektor=streichen(kraftvektor,0);//FEHLER vermutet
    kraftvektor=streichen(kraftvektor,kraftvektor.length-2);//FEHLER vermutet
    kraftvektor=streichen(kraftvektor,kraftvektor.length-2);//FEHLER vermutet



    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Brückensimulation");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(null);
    addWindowListener(new WindowHandler());
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHandler());
    addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());

    zeich=new Zeichnen();
    zeich.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    add(zeich);

    einstellungen=new JButton("Einstellungen ändern");
    einstellungen.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    einstellungen.setBounds(40,437,190,30);
    add(einstellungen);

    zurueck=new JButton("Zurück");
    zurueck.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    zurueck.setBounds(260,437,190,30);
    add(zurueck);


}
double[][] streichen(double[][] m,int linie){
    double[][] t;
    if(m.length==1){
        t=new double[m.length][m[0].length-1];
    }else if(m[0].length==1){
        t=new double[m.length-1][m[0].length];
    }else{
        t=new double[m.length-1][m[0].length-1];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m[0].length;j++){
            if(i!=linie&&j!=linie){
                int a=i,b=j;
                if(i>linie){
                    a=i-1;
                }
                if(j>linie){
                    b=j-1;
                }
                t[a][b]=m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}

private class Zeichnen extends JLabel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -138735436009377046L;
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D graphics=(Graphics2D)g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        hintergrund.paintIcon(this,graphics,-200,-50);

        ergebnisvektor=Hauptprogramm.multiplyMatrices(Hauptprogramm.inverse_matrix(gesamtsteifigkeitsmatrix),kraftvektor);//FEHLER vermutet

        for(int i=1;i<kraftvektor.length/3+1;i++){
            punkte[i].setGewicht(ergebnisvektor[3*i-1][0]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<fe_anzahl;i++){
            xKoordinaten[i]=fe_laengepixel*i+40;
            yKoordinaten[i]=punkte[i].getGewicht()*scale+200;
        }
        rescale();
        for(int i=0;i<fe_anzahl;i++){ 
            if(i>=1){                   
                graphics.drawLine((int)xKoordinaten[i-1],(int)yKoordinaten[i-1],(int)xKoordinaten[i],(int)yKoordinaten[i]);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<fe_anzahl;i++){
            if(i==0||i==fe_anzahl-1){
                graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            }else{
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            graphics.fillOval((int)xKoordinaten[i]-5,(int)yKoordinaten[i]-5,10,10);
        }
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        graphics.drawLine(0, 430, 500, 430);//Trennlinie

        graphics.drawLine(450-(int)fe_laengepixel, 415, 450, 415);//Maßstab x
        graphics.fillRect(450-(int)fe_laengepixel, 410, 2, 10);
        graphics.fillRect(450, 410, 2, 10);
        graphics.drawString(new Double(Math.round(fe_laengereal*1000)/1000.0).toString()+"m",450-(int)fe_laengepixel+10 , 410);

        graphics.drawLine(475, 200, 475, 410);//Maßstab y
        graphics.fillRect(470, 200, 10, 2);
        graphics.fillRect(470, 410, 10, 2);
        double k=Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for(double i:yKoordinaten){
            if(i>k){
                k=i;
            }
        }
        k-=200;
        graphics.drawString(new Double(Math.round(k/scale*1000)/1000.0).toString()+"m",430 ,345);
    }
    public Point getPolylinePoint(int i){
        return new Point((int)xKoordinaten[i]+2,(int)yKoordinaten[i]+26);
    }
    void rescale(){
        double k=Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for(double i:yKoordinaten){
            if(i>k){
                k=i;
            }
        }
        k-=200;
        for(int i=0;i<yKoordinaten.length;i++){
            if(k!=0){
                scale=200/k;
                yKoordinaten[i]=(int)((yKoordinaten[i]-200)*scale+200);
            }
        }
    }

}
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==einstellungen){
            new EinstellungenDialog(SimulationFenster.this);
        }else if( e.getSource()==zurueck){
            SimulationFenster.this.dispose();
            new MenuFenster();
        }
    }

}
private class WindowHandler implements WindowListener{

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        SimulationFenster.this.dispose();
        new MenuFenster();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}

}
private class MouseHandler implements MouseInputListener{
    //MouseMotionListener
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        boolean anyif=false;    
        for(int i=1;i<fe_anzahl-1;i++){
            if(e.getPoint().distance(zeich.getPolylinePoint(i))<5){
                setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                anyif=true;
            }
        }
        if(!anyif){
            setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
    }
    //MouseListener
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        for(int i=1;i<fe_anzahl-1;i++){
            if(e.getPoint().distance(zeich.getPolylinePoint(i))<5){
                new FiniteElementeDialog(SimulationFenster.this,i,kraftvektor);
                repaint();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

}

I hope that someone has the time to help us. `//FEHLER vermutet` is a comment that marks suspicious looking parts of the code.

Comment: can you provide a SSCCE? Also, unrelated but that code is inefficient. Try using a full matrix library such as http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library/ejml/0.16

Comment: And write 100 times *algor**i**thm*! It has arabian roots, not greek ones…

Comment: @zmo: actually, Persian roots, the author of the "al-gibr" book was from a religious group (and city?), with name something like Khoresm, in Persia.

Comment: @user3696463: Please check very carefully if your task really requires the inversion of the matrix. In almost all cases, what is required is the solution of linear systems with that matrix, and for that, a matrix factorization like PLU or QR is completely sufficient.